# Related to 404 and ajax (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, http-status-code-404

I've been scouting around Google in hope that it could push me in the right way on how to do it, but sadly I couldn't find any... So my question is basically:

Is it possible to have a 404 pop up show up instead of it being a page?|

I'm currently creating a onepager and it'd be nice to have a pop up showing a 404 message instead of linking it to a 404 page.

If there is such thing, could I be pushed in the right direction?

Thanks in advance,
Ahmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do two things :

1. Add an .htaccess file to your root and redirect all other urls to your homepage say index.html with a parameter like #/404
2. In your index file, call a function on DOM ready and get the current url. If it contains 404 then add the pop-up..

Code :

```
var currentUrl = window.location.pathname;
```

Reference URL : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.location

Just an idea.. Code-work you can do easily..

Answer (score 0):

Doesnt work, at least i dont think so. Popups have to be written on a page, but theres no page where you could write. You could create a php-file which you use as "container" for the popup, and when the user enters it, you immediatly send him to the previous file via the function "header". Just an idea, dont know if this might work.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.header.php